# Faye, Rails and Net:HTTP end of file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I am trying to accomplish the following task: as soon a post is approved on the site, people on this site will be informed of that.

To solve this I am using Faye, and publishing on the channel on my method approve. My application has only one channel, really simple scenario. Anyway, for some reason it is not working.

I am using **Rails 2.3.5**, **Faye 0.8.5**, **eventmachine 1.0.0.beta4** (the one installed with Faye), **rack 1.0.1**, and **thin 1.3.1**. I am not using Apache.

What I have so far is:

**faye.ru**: (I run it with: rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production)

```
require 'faye'

faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

**application.js**:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye');
  faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    alert(data.text);
  });
});
```

**application.html.erb**:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye.js' %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**:

```
def approve
  @post.update_attribute(:approved, true)
  message = {:post => @post}
  uri = URI.parse("http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye")
  Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :message => message.to_json)
  redirect_to(pending_posts_path)
end
```

The **stack** trace is:

```
EOFError (end of file reached):
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2024:in `read_status_line'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2013:in `read_new'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in `request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:405:in `post_form'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:404:in `post_form'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:38:in `approve'
```

And on the thin server an **error** also appears:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
```

As far as I understood, this error appears everytime I try to connect on the server, and a critical thing is that "http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye.js" is not available, i.e., if I try to access this URL, I receive "**!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass**", and that is the same reason why Net:HTTP can't access it. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, my fault, I forgot to start listening with the server, on faye.ru:

```
faye_server.listen(9292)
```

Answer (score 1):

dont type `<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://0.0.0.0:9292/faye.js' %>`

it's not exactly localhost, just do:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'http://127.0.0.1:9292/faye.js' %>`

Comment: Thanks for your help, at some point I ended up giving up of trying with Faye, but know that you pointed that out, I am going to set it up again, and test it. I am going to return with the outcomes. Thanks!

Comment: does not work, I've tried and still the same issues. Thanks anyway.